# Scala for comprehension - chaining Future with IndexedSeq

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

Is it possible to achieve something like this:

```
for {
  numberOfLines <- Future { getNumberOfLines() }
  i <- 0 to numberOfLines
  result <- Future { extractResultFromLine(i) }
} yield result
```

I hope it is clear what my intentions are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Future.traverse`

```
// Gives you a Future[IndexedSeq[`whatever extractResult returns`]]
for {
    numberOfLines <- Future{getNumberOfLines()}
    result <- Future.traverse(0 to numberOfLines)(i => Future(extractResultFromLine(i)))
} yield result
```

Comment: Thanks! And what if the body of for looks like this?: i <- 0 to numberOfLines; j = i % 5; k = i * 2; result <- Future(dowhatever(j, k))